# wordpress: extend the width of the footer widget area

Tags: css, wordpress

I don't have that much css skills, but I want to extend the width of the footer widget area, so that it fills the whole screen width (now there is a small stripe on the left and on the right). I can't find the code where to adjust it. 
Is there anybody who can help me???
Thank you!
Kind regards,
pradhana

Comment: we would need more info or an example to help you, like the html and css code of your footer in your current setup

Comment: Here is the css of my current footer:

Comment: #footer {
 display: block;
 overflow: visible;
 width: 100%;
 border-top: 1px solid transparent;
}

#footer-inside {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 2em;
}

#footer:after {
 display: table;
 clear: both;
 content: "";
}

Comment: #colophon a,
#footer a {
 -webkit-transition: color .2s;
 transition: color .2s;
}

#site-copyright {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 clear: left;
 font-style: regular;
 font-size: .9em;
 /*line-height: 1.5;*/
}

#footer a,#footer a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
}

img#wpstats {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto .5em;
}

Comment: .footermenu {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.footermenu > ul {}

.footermenu ul li {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.footermenu ul li span.sep {
 margin: 0 1em;
 font-size: .6em;
}

Comment: .footermenu ul li:last-child span.sep {
 display: none;
}

.footermenu ul li a {
 font-size: .9em;
 font-weight: 400;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

Comment: and the html part? maybe you can paste it in a fiddle, so we understand the problem easily: https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: #colophon {
 width: 100%;
}

#colophon-inside {
 display: block;
 float: none;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 -moz-flex: 1;
 -ms-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
 -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 min-height: 100%;
 margin: 2em auto 0;
 max-width: 100%;
}

Comment: Where can I find the html? What do you mean with fiddle?

Comment: Here is a footer.php file. Do you mean this one?

Comment: Sorry, I am a non-expert.

Comment: i added a link for jsfiddle in my comment above, there you can paste the css and html to reproduce the problem, so we can look at it

Comment: Oh, sorry. I haven't recognized. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/1hrdg142/1/

Comment: Sorry that does not really help, can you paste the HTML code you see in browser instead of the php file?

Comment: Ok. https://jsfiddle.net/1hrdg142/2/ Just in case, here is the link for the page: www.veda-vit.de

Comment: if i understand the question correctly -> if you change the content css to `#content { padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;}` it should work

Comment: Unbelievable! Great! :) Thank you so much!